# How to infer a deep object keys types with functions arguments in TS?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I'm trying to understand how Typescript would allow me to infer the keys of a route object. Here are my relevant types:

```js
type Route = {
    layout: (props: PropsWithChildren) => EmotionJSX.Element;
    prefix: string;
    routes: Record<Uppercase<string>, Page>;
}

const auth = {
    layout: AuthLayout,
    prefix: "/auth",
    routes: {
        LOGIN: {
            path: "/login",
            component: lazy(() => import("../pages/Login"))
        },
    }
} satisfies Route;

const user = {
    layout: UserLayout,
    prefix: "/user",
    routes: {
        DASHBOARD: {
            path: "/dashboard",
            component: lazy(() => import("../pages/User/Dashboard"))
        },
    }
} satisfies Route;

export { user, auth };
```

So I'm working on a getRoutePath() function that takes 2 arguments: route type, and route name. That function can take one of the route type (user or auth) as first parameter, and one of the keys of the routes properties as second parameter, and return the path for the route.
I've successfully managed to write the functions, and it works fine, it infers the routes types and the keys of the route object.

```js
import ROUTES from "./constants/routes"

const getRoutePath= <T extends keyof typeof ROUTES, R extends keyof typeof ROUTES[T]["routes"]>(type: T, name: R): string | false => {
    if (!ROUTES[type]) return false;
    if (!params) params = {};

    let path = "";
    if (ROUTES[type].prefix) path = ROUTES[type].prefix;

    if (ROUTES[type].routes[name].path) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ => This is throwing an error

        path += ROUTES[type].routes[name].path;
    }
    return path;
}
```

I can successfully use getRoutePath("admin", "DASHBOARD"), and not getRoutePath("admin", "NOTHING"). Nevertheless, ts says that there is an error in the function: type R cannot be used to index type { DASHBOARD: { path: string; component: LazyExoticComponent<() => Element>; }; } | { ...; } | { ...; }

I don't understand why TS is throwing an error here.

I've tried to strong type my routes instead of using satisfies, but when I do so I can't infer the function's second argument anymore. I've tried to create a makeRoute function to force the functions definition, but I still get the same error.

Here is a link to a reproductible example: [Typescriptland.org play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgRBTAZgSwHb0gQwDbawB322QGNMAXZAe1UgCcqBXc%20AZyhGHHIE98MACpgDmGALyQA3lEiz8FABYAuSK3J00wgNwzZlctngq1G1NvABfcNz4YASkxaQJ02bOyYej4%20s063kPh0SMgAHj6m5gEMzGwqdvAkVHQAJgA8AKqE8HRkrPBpJpoAfAA0kEKixTpW4EmoaljMCs5SupAeXswqAESYzT2l7UEh4ZA9wP3kCoPtMSysKq4BbgAyAPIA4gCSAHJL7Stu8tO9wNhUwmizR0f6hr0AwjToodSoN7cWQwFWFqoUZCsFBsSAOWI6Oo0RqMfJ0VrLdyebzjWE5T5yYIoMYTNF0DH0RxxNq3OAAQQAygAJABC6zJdlgB1JAROynGwBSmFYCgARlRMKkCaT7kZxgAVTC8wz9SApDD8oU-L7K2R-AGUYHIUHgliQ%20qNTApAC2aAR7U6KL6JuuqsCWLCZyNpo%20dvmxMRK1glNp9MZzJZckUZy5PP5gpSwtuot6QlQ6FlKQA5M60ED1ICaFG1Xb1axAVqdUTIcBgJAaRgyFjGNhylMWjymNgUpBeRgPGo66w5Uh%20thyITYlCGgP3d2XFgbahyni681IBZ9dCB6JyLr4EJpq00uLIPBQixUCluwBreBeRCQXj8KiXsflOx7g-wI%20n8%203q%202D9jgDa4oAuj%20PRjj0-7FO0AAU15iuK5SoJgxpinY5TyHQCGLGCiTJOkRRmOUuHCMUCLfJAACOjA5Dw8RYakhS%20Hhqj0YRxEAJQRJozhEZ6yCXhBACEv7Qf%20LH0PA5CMHQtA9D0-huDxkD8ah6EiUpxrjlIi7WAEhgDmyrTSbJsjyRBgm2P%20AB0IzYipiitKZ-AWVZYSQgExn2fAFm-vBiGOYoImeqytkANQSO5nlEqwP7eR5lmKIZC5aW46y8gAVok5DmWePCsBBqmsCx5mIMkACimAkAoEFZZxJK3HpEhsuZwREGV8AQQABkoAAkkhZRYbUoYK6E-llwnxRYLEuXJvHkZR-mHG4BoDjNdA8BSTGtOgADukAZHYqwUvAgrlUIaFqRBy08AV5BUGtkQQRN81BluIXjAA-D0kBBWRFErbdfjtLU0RiRJtBsjU1gGlQhjmRcwgQau66bhV1ouoM4zetSdIMrAPQsSxw6sFD8Aw5c8NiYjigQX0AzlD0Gw7LsuP45D0Ow2Ta5EkjVN4mjPS7OsuzFQAGtsFLisVuzikzQA)

Comment: Could you add a playground link with all components in order for us to have a reproducible example?

Comment: @Nullndr : done, added at the end

Comment: The isue is essentially [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the compiler widens the value types from a union-constrained generic to the full union, and then loses the thread. If you want the compiler to see type safety you can refactor as in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which, for the problematic part of your code, is as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WYeZQW). If you don't care you should assert your way through as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WkEKlN). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @jcalz , I apreciate. That's exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I will use

```
type Routes = typeof routes;
```

to make it easier to discuss.

---

The problem is that when you index into a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)-typed value with a specific key, the compiler tends to first widen the type of the generic to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) (as mentioned in [a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194)).  Inside `getRoutePath()`, this means that while `routes[type]` is seen as the generic type `Routes[T]`, `routes[type].routes` is widened to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
const r = routes[type].routes;
/* const r: {
    LOGIN: {
        path: string;
        title: string;
    };
} | {
    DASHBOARD: {
        path: string;
        title: string;
    };
} | {
    DASHBOARD: {
        path: string;
        title: string;
    };
} */
```

at which point the compiler loses track of the correlation between that type and the type `R extends keyof Routes[T]["routes"]` of `name`, and won't let you index `routes[type].routes[name]`.

This is similar to the issue reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) where you have two union-typed values which are correlated to each other in a way that they are always compatible, but the compiler doesn't understand.

---

The best way to fix it depends on your use case.  If you're confident that you've done the right thing and just want the compiler to stop complaining, you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) your way through:

```
const r = routes[type].routes as Record<R, { path: string }>; 
if (r[name].path) {
    path += r[name].path;
}
```

*You* know that `routes[type].routes` has a `{path: string}`-compatible value at the `R` index, so you can just tell the compiler that and move on.  The compiler can't *verify* that, so you've taken some of the responsibility for type safety away from the compiler.

If you don't want to do that and would like the compiler to follow the logic well enough to complain if you make a mistake, then you'll need to refactor in a way similar to that described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which is the recommended approach to dealing with correlated unions as described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.

Essentially you need to rewrite your types so that they are explicitly in terms of generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  In your case it could look like this:

```
type RouteRoutes = { [T in keyof Routes]:
    keyof Routes[T]["routes"]
};
/* type RouteRoutes = {
  admin: "DASHBOARD";
  user: "DASHBOARD";
  auth: "LOGIN";
} */

type _Routes = { [T in keyof Routes]:
    { routes: Record<RouteRoutes[T], { path: string }> }
};
const _routes: _Routes = routes; // okay
```

Here we've made a `RouteRoutes` type that is a simple mapping from the keys of `Routes` to the keys of the `routes` properties at those keys.  And then `_Routes` is a version of `Routes` that captures the relationship in `RouteRoutes` explicitly as a mapped type.  And we are allowed to assign `routes` to a variable `_routes` of type `Routes`.

Then we refactor `getRoutePath`'s `R` type to be constrained to `RouteRoutes[T]`:

```
const getRoutePath = <T extends keyof Routes, R extends RouteRoutes[T]>(
    type: T, name: R,
    params: Record<string, string> = {},
    query: Record<string, string> = {}
): string => { /* ✂ ⋯ ✂ */ }
```

And now, inside of the function, if we index into `_routes[type].routes` instead of `routes[type].routes`, the compiler sees it as generic in `R`:

```
    const r: Record<R, { path: string }> = _routes[type].routes;
```

And that means you can index into it with `R` without error:

```
    if (_routes[type].routes[name].path) {
        path += _routes[type].routes[name].path;
    }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DoKALgngDgpgBABQIYHN4F44G8Rz3KJMACwC44BnMAJwEsA7FAbl3zFrABsZyq7GWAXxDho8AEoB7AK5gM2Vnk5IIMsLxoNmigtRgAzWgA8N-bfjjU1MCuXEwAxpOoATADwBVKLGoOkFGDc+LQA+ABpEVBgQoREneio4JFliOEwcC2VVWXIAImSSXLCdKD1DEzhcgHoC4iKdK1kbcgyLfAAZAHkAcQBJADkWnTb8QhI8qs5JFAZ6kZH2Lh5KgGFJenoYI1p1ufnBYothQUoiWgpDGzgpJpYQeMTpAOo0hUyVNTynmGo9vFKDMYJt9fod8I05LY3vMACIAQQAygAJABCnTh4hhQ3mbTGZEqVRc-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-KSmp5TjfPmayqJosrLIsXc7uoCAEVY15NgAdzgDxxHaBEvV8YhkEw3TYJeiAhrASR3rMWCrse0YFuqyoAH5cjgSrKOo164a0C62mESy9DkhT4pIQniaertJG4OyphQWD90PY8pvyNV9QiXJTVRdFMVyTjOJ3Wn6cZ5nZNZlzYPyFIikqLo+n6QXhZphI6ZgBnpglg9rDZmWQXl3J+k6fpRoADV6BF6VG-p6RVu5iaKigZ3nJcV3sFsHBhsxtwsVM-zkZ95TgICrMUn900DmxgNISzI6fIKQLAiDgL5QmqgAKhpMRo+D9JnX9eg8l580BcJvAQRLxE+YtCyRlqPJFYGev8BOTOqhavAA4AfXz7BQ-POUE+jihY8suKezo3D3EPZ8gOA2KKfxJjktHdORYSSUe6nuA+6TV4eyYVLc0kW8VC7uBdxZvWFswM930-O8Hyj59X0fmBrwi6x55AkJYMsghOASE4BFTQpZAa08opMRYmYdi+lQz4EhlAvCMDKCsXgVgYQFhuLoN9ugfil8LDWTEkFSS0lSbyUUuZCu+ASEDWcmDPSWDrojGMsvMyrcRj5TISFRyxhnInkCv+YKsASreSMKwto-kUGzyXjaPBvFBDwJ3rwsRoUsxELocJVRIj7LiSKiVFyD1qTIxPKjXRkJRH1QMXVIxlNLLU1ah1LqPUHx9QYcNMaE0pozQIXNeYplMBLT0KtCaMBNo7T2g+A6R0mGnQfOdRxiM8rCUhiY0xV8uySkhvjJKmBvq-X+oDCkk1QZYQhrjKGdkYZ5KZojTJHDUa5AxljHGNE6m0LwE4kYlDyZ4ippfB4GstZMxvk0fWHM9RG1LvzGEKtN4UBGeLcZchJm1CNs3ZWQtFnLO1qso80tciG25ibM2ltra23tjswQQA)